# Как разместить большую картинку в div блоке?

Tags: html, css

не могу разобраться с проблемой. Необходимо разместить картинку с большими размерами в **div**, который по размерам меньше картинки. Но чтобы картинка в блоке отображалась нормально и не обрезалась.
Блок **div** должен быть адаптивным.

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 33.3%;
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300') no-repeat center;
}

.img-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <a href="" class="img-button">Go to</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. **Вариант:**

   ```
   .img {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto; 
   }
   ```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 33.3%;
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
}

.img-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300" class="img" />
  <a href="" class="img-button">Go to</a>
</div>
```

2. **Вариант (если обертка картинки с фиксированной высотой):**

   ```
    .img {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       -o-object-fit: cover;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
   ```

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 33.3%;
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.img-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300" class="img" />
  <a href="" class="img-button">Go to</a>
</div>
```

3. **Вариант:**

   ```
   .img {
     background-size: cover; 
   }
   ```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 33.3%;
  min-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/id/237/400/300') center no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:280px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <a href="" class="img-button">Go to</a>
</div>
```

Comment: ссылка на картинку должна быть в CSS коде

Comment: Картинка не должна обрезаться

Comment: Так чтобы в стилях путь к изображению, на весь блок и не обрезалось, тогда `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: но при этом может нарушится соотношение сторон и картинка исказится.